# Incorrect syntax near 'System'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Editprofile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProfileCS"].ConnectionString;

            string sql = "select userid from Profile";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(dr);
            ddl_userid.DataSource = dt;
            ddl_userid.DataTextField = "userid";
            ddl_userid.DataValueField = "userid";
            ddl_userid.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void ddl_userid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProfileCS"].ConnectionString;

        string sql = "Select studname,gender,email,birthdate,contact from profile where userid='" + ddl_userid.SelectedValue + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dt.Load(dr);

        tb_studname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["studname"].ToString();
        tb_gender.Text = dt.Rows[0]["gender"].ToString();
        tb_email.Text = dt.Rows[0]["email"].ToString();
        tb_age.Text = dt.Rows[0]["birthdate"].ToString();
        tb_contact.Text = dt.Rows[0]["contact"].ToString();
        Session["dt"] = dt;
    }
    protected void bn_reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
        tb_studname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["studname"].ToString();
        tb_gender.Text = dt.Rows[0]["gender"].ToString();
        tb_email.Text = dt.Rows[0]["email"].ToString();
        tb_age.Text = dt.Rows[0]["birthdate"].ToString();
        tb_contact.Text = dt.Rows[0]["contact"].ToString();

    }
    protected void bn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProfileCS"].ConnectionString;

        String name = tb_studname.Text;
        String gender = tb_gender.Text;
        String email = tb_email.Text;
        String age = tb_age.Text;
        String contact = tb_contact.Text;

        string sql="Update Profile Set studName='"+name+"',gender='"+gender+"',email='"+email+"',birthdate='"+age+"',contact='"+contact; 
        sql=sql +"where userid='"+ddl_userid+"'";

        SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText=sql;
        cmd.Connection=con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lbl_msg.Text="Record Updated!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            lbl_msg.Text="Problem encountered:"+ex.Message;

        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }


    }
}
```

HI guys when i load the page the reset button works as intended but when i try the update info button error message occurs as such
Problem encountered:Incorrect syntax near 'System'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''

Comment: On which line exactly? What is the type of your `userid` column and what is the value of `ddl_userid.SelectedValue` exactly? And please be aware of _SQL Injection_ attacks.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @SonerGönül userid is nvarchar(50) and what do you mean the value of ddl_userid.SelectedValue

Comment: Agree on the Sql Injection comment - plus, the syntax error you are encountering sounds like a common error that occurs when concatenating sql statements.  Using Sql parameters will automatically handle special characters, including quotation marks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Answer (score 5):

The error is in missing close quote in the update statement

```
 string sql="Update Profile Set studName='"+name+"',gender='"+gender+"',email='"+
            email+"',birthdate='"+age+"',contact='"+contact +"'";
```

Said that, you should remove all this string concatenation and use a parameterized query

There are too many point to fix, I just show a proposed fix for the Update

```
  string sql="Update Profile Set studName=@name,gender=@gender,email=@email," + 
             "birthdate=@age,contact=@contact where userid=@uid";

   SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = sql;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender",gender);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",email);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age",age);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact",contact);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid",ddl_userid);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In this way your command string is more readable and you avoid subtle quoting errors.
Also the work to quote your parameters is passed to the framework code and there is no possibility of SQL Injections.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in this line;

```
string sql="Update Profile Set studName='"+name+"',gender='"+gender+"',email='"+email+"',birthdate='"+age+"',
contact='"+contact;
                 ^^ here missing '"
sql=sql +"where userid='"+ddl_userid+"'";
```

**But please don't use this way**. Use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead. This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also using parameterized queries increases readability.

For example;

```
string sql = @"Update Profile Set studName=@studName,gender=@gender,email=@email, birthdate=@birthdate, contact=@contact 
               where userid=@userid";
SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studName", studName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", birthdate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contact);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: thanks all but dont worry about attacks its just a basic school project with beginnner c# knowledge!

Comment: @sherrez: **especially** if you're a learner - you should learn the **PROPER** way of doing it! Don't learn the crappy, hacky way - then you'll just keep on doing this your whole life! Make the **effort NOW** to learn how to do this **PROPERLY** - once and for all !

Comment: @mark_s I agree with you about the proper way to do things but the actual question was what was wrong with the code, not what is wrong with the coding techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with Following line:

```
string sql="Update Profile Set studName='"+name+"',gender='"+gender+"',email='"+email+"',birthdate='"+age+"',contact='"+contact;
```

You need to complete the string as follow : see I have edited end of the statement.

```
string sql="Update Profile Set studName='"+name+"',gender='"+gender+"',email='"+email+"',birthdate='"+age+"',contact='"+contact +"' ";
```

**Note :** I am suggesting to you that you should use parameterized query instead of making direct string.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
string sql="Update Profile Set studName='"+name+"',gender='"+gender+"',email='"+email+"',birthdate='"+age+"',contact='"+contact;
```

To:

```
string sql="Update Profile Set studName='"+name+"',gender='"+gender+"',email='"+email+"',birthdate='"+age+"',contact='"+contact + "' ";
```

Missing the single quote after contact.  Then you need a space so that the next line that adds Where clause works.